# Javascript function which returns different values on every invoke

Tags: javascript

Write a function which fulfill the criteria:

1. on the first invoke return 0
2. on every next invoke return next integer: 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
3. not passing any parameters
4. not use global variables (or external ones)

It looks like that it cannot be done on simple loop. So what you think is the  right approach to solve this? Maybe you know how to do it?

I have found that using IIFE in that case is useful:

```
let giveMeMore = (function () { 
let i = 0 //private variable 

const iterator = function() { 
return i++ //operation on private variable
} 
return iterator 
})() 
giveMeMore() 
giveMeMore() 
giveMeMore() 
giveMeMore()
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Maybe a generator?

Comment: We're not here to solve your puzzles. The whole point of this exercise is for you to figure it out yourself.

Comment: @Barmar i have solved 

Comment: so right, what is a closure?

Comment: ...and yet, three people (at this moment) _have_ solved the puzzle for the OP, and _worse_, did not even provide an explanation for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const func = (function () { return this.i++ }).bind({ i: 0 })

console.log(func())
console.log(func())
console.log(func())
console.log(func())
```

Answer (score 0):

So here what this code is doing, let's try to understand

- First here we have a function assigned to variable `func`.
- Inside function we are adding a property named `value` which we keep updating on each function invocation

```js
var func = function value(){
  func.value = func.value || 0
  console.log(func.value)
  func.value++
}
func()
func()
func()
```